# How can I paste code at the position of the cursor in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

When I paste (ctrl+v) code in a certain line, the code is always pasted at the start of the line, regardless of what the position of the cursor is on that line at the time of pasting.

How can I paste at the position of the cursor?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when pasting in androdi studio it does not consider the position of the cursor, there is no way of "fixing" this, just tab the code forward.